# Show that the tangent plane of the saddle surface $z=xy$ at any point intersects the surface in a pair of lines.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

My attempt: Let $f(x,y,z)=xy-z$ , (a,b,c)$\in$the saddle surface, and calculate the total derivative $Df(a,b,c)=(b,a,-1)$ Then the tangent plane is $$g(x,y,z)=f(a,b,c)+Df(a,b,c)(x-a,y-b,c-z)=bx+ay-z+ab$$
Set $g(x,y,z)=f(x,y,z)$ to get the intersection got $bx+ay-xy+ab=0$. 
I know that the equation can be written as $$bx+ay-xy+ab=bx-ay-z-c=0$$ But I have no idea to get a pair of lines which intersects the saddle surface.

Comment: Is the surface that you’re talking about the level set $xy-z=0$, then?

Comment: This problem isn’t really very different from the one in [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3683283/265466). The way to solve each of them is similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you made an error in the calculation:
$$\begin{align}
g(x,y,z)=f(a,b,c)+Df(a,b,c)(x-a,y-b,\color{red}{z-c})&=bx+ay-z\color{red}{+c-2ab}\\
&=bx+ay-z\color{red}{-ab}
\end{align}
$$
where we used $ab-c=0$.

Now the intersection of the surfaces can be found from the equation:
$$
xy-z=bx+ay-z-ab\implies (x-a)(y-b)=0,
$$
which solutions are $x=a$ and $y=b$.

Substituting the values into equation of any of two surfaces one obtains that the intersection lines are:
$$
\begin {cases}x-a=0\\
ay-z=0
\end {cases}\quad\text {and}\quad
\begin {cases}y-b=0\\
 bx-z=0
\end {cases}.
$$

Comment: Those last two equations are those of planes, not lines.

Comment: @amd Of course one should see the equations in combination with the previous ones: $y=b$ and $x=a $, respectively.  Should I underline the point in the answer?

Comment: Absolutely, since that’s not at all what you wrote: “... the intersection lines **are** ...” followed by equations of two planes.

Comment: @amd Please check my edit.

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: thanks!! I got it.